# How to plot two GeoDataFrames with one legend in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, geopandas

I have the following code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

states_gdf = gpd.read_file('https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_5m.zip')
CO_gdf = states_gdf[states_gdf['STUSPS'] == 'CO']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CO_gdf.plot(ax = ax, column = 'STUSPS')
CO_gdf.boundary.to_frame().plot(ax = ax, color = 'k', label = 'CO Boundary')
```

I want to have one legend, that labels both the colored-in region and the boundary.

If I try the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
CO_gdf.plot(ax = ax, column = 'STUSPS', legend = True)
CO_gdf.boundary.to_frame().plot(ax = ax, color = 'k', label = 'CO Boundary')
ax.legend()
```

The first legend gets deleted when the second one is plotted.

I've also tried collecting the handles and labels manually with `ax.get_legend_handles_labels()`, but for some reason the first plot line `CO_gdf.plot(...)` doesn't seem to create any handles.

Comment: Try adding `label='Something'` in `CO_gdf.plot(...)`.

Comment: Doesn't work. Only "CO Boundary" is in the legend.